# Replicating GLM::perspective in code

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm having trouble understanding glm::perspective. I know what it does, but don't understand the mechanism. Does anyone know what the source code / procedure is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [glm::perspective explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115352/glmperspective-explanation)

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115352/glmperspective-explanation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all open-source, look at [the code](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/0.9.5/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl#L207-L229):

```cpp
template <typename valType>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER detail::tmat4x4<valType, defaultp> perspective
(
    valType const & fovy,
    valType const & aspect,
    valType const & zNear,
    valType const & zFar
)
{
    assert(aspect != valType(0));
    assert(zFar != zNear);

#ifdef GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
    valType const rad = fovy;
#else
#   pragma message("GLM: perspective function taking degrees as a parameter is deprecated.     #define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS before including GLM headers to remove this message.")
    valType const rad = glm::radians(fovy);
#endif

    valType tanHalfFovy = tan(rad / valType(2));

    detail::tmat4x4<valType, defaultp> Result(valType(0));
    Result[0][0] = valType(1) / (aspect * tanHalfFovy);
    Result[1][1] = valType(1) / (tanHalfFovy);
    Result[2][2] = - (zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear);
    Result[2][3] = - valType(1);
    Result[3][2] = - (valType(2) * zFar * zNear) / (zFar - zNear);
    return Result;
}
```

...which creates a matrix as per the [`gluPerspective()` documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).