# 2D Texture morph in Ortographic Projection

Tags: opengl, textures, depth, orthographic

I'm having a hard time figuring out what's going on with my texture:

Basically I am fetching a webcam stream as my underlying 2d texture canvas in OpenGL, and in my paintGL() I'm drawing stuff on it (as RGBA images with GL_BLEND).
Since I'm using a Kinect as a data source, I'm also getting the depth values from a tracked skeleton (a person), and converting them into GL values (XYZ varying between 0.0f and 1.0f). 
So my goal is that, for instance, a loaded 2D Texture like a shirt, is now properly tracking the person in my RGB output display. But it seems my understanding of orthographic projection is wrong:

I'm constantly loading the 4 converted vertices into a VBO, but whenever I put the texture on top of this dynamic quad, it's always facing the screen. 
I thought that putting this dynamic quad between the "background" canvas and the camera would result in a proper projection of the quad onto the canvas, which would give me the impression of a warping 2D texture, that seems to "bend" whenever the person rotates.

But the texture is **always** facing the camera and doesnt rotate.
I've also tried to manually rotate via a matrix and set that into my shader, but again, it only rotates the vertice quad itself (as: rotation simply makes the texture smaller) , and THEN puts the texture on top, instead of rotating the texture with it.

So, is it somehow possible to properly apply this to the texture?
I've thought about mixing a perspective projection in, but actually have no idea how to implement this...

**EDIT:**
I've actually already set my projection matrix up like the following:

In *resizeGL()*:

```
projection.setToIdentity();
projection.ortho(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, -5.0f);
projection.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
```

In *paintGL()*:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);  // turning this on/off makes no difference
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, &textureID);

program.setUniformValue("mvp_matrix", projection);
program.setUniformValue("texture", 0);
//draw 2d background quad
drawQuad();

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// switch to frustum to give perspective view
projection.setToIdentity();
projection.frustum(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, -5.0f);
projection.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);

// bind cloth texture and draw ontop 2d quad
clothTexture->bind();
program.setUniformValue("mpv_matrix", projection);
drawShirtQuad();

// reset to ortho view
projection.setToIdentity();
projection.ortho(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, -5.0f);

// release texture
clothTexture->release();
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

*clothTexture* is a QOpenGLTexture that has successfully loaded an RGBA image from a file. 
Result: whenever I activate the frustum perspective, it results in a black screen. I think everything is correctly set up: POV is traversed towards positive z-axis in resizeGL(), and all the cloth vertices vary between 0 and 1 in XYZ, while the background is positioned at:

> (0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), (1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), (1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f), (0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f).

So the cloth object is always positioned between background plane and POV. Am i missing something in the frustum setup ? I've simply set it up the same way as ortho...

**EDIT:**
Sorry for not mentiong; the matrix I'm using is a QMatrix4x4 type:
[Frustum](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmatrix4x4.html#frustum)

These functions multiply the current matrix with the one you define as an argument, which should yield the same result as if I define a View matrix for instance, and then define my shader uniform "mvp_matrix" as projection * view, if I'm not mistaken. Maybe something like [lookAt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmatrix4x4.html#lookAt) will do the trick; I'll just try messing around more. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a perspective projection to achieve desired result. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115352/glmperspective-explanation) for example code for perspective projection matrix creation with glm.

Moving vertices wouldn't be needed as you will get proper positions with rotation applied in your model matrix.

**EDIT**: in your code where can i look at **.frustum** and **.translate** methods or from what library **projection** object is? It doesn't look like you are doing Projection * View by moving frustum matrix. [Some info](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/#The_View_matrix) about roles of standard matrices.

Considering debugging if you get on screen black color instead of **GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT** color problem is not with matrix but earlier. Also i recommend to console.log your perspective matrix and compare it to correct one (which you can get for example in **glm** library).

Comment: Thanks for answering; I've updated my post above and added a frustum perspective...